# Referencing CSV file in Select By Attributes SQL query?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, sql, select-by-attribute

I have 2 databases:

Database 1: Point Shapefile with adress and APN (parcel numbers) as attributes. (Huge number of points, addresses for an entire metropolitan area).

Database 2: CSV file with a smaller database of addresses and APN numbers, and a few other fields. This one is not georeferenced.

I would like to construct a query in Select by Attributes where I reference database 2 and search for APN's within database 1 corresponding to all the ones in database 2. Ultimately I would like to isolate all corresponding points and display them on the map.

This is like a batch form of the following query:

SELECT*FROM ADDRESS_APN WHERE "APN" = '###' AND "APN"='####' AND ......

Only thing is there are about 565 values so it is unfeasible to have an AND statement for each value. I would much rather reference the CSV file.

Comment: A CSV file is not a database. If you want query performance, you should load the CSV into a file geodatabase and create an index.

Comment: I'm not familiar with file geodatabases... any extra hints you could provide? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you could stomach writing 565 `AND` statements, that wouldn't give you what you wanted. What you're actually seeking to do is known as a [table join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002q000000). You want to select the records of one of your tables that have a match in the other table. Once you have your tables loaded in ArcGIS (and you will probably need to load your CSV to something indexed by ArcGIS) you want to perform a join according to your APN field, ignoring all records that don't exist in both tables.

Comment: Thank you, I will further document myself on this and let you know how it works out...